# Descriptive statistics for a frequency table

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Let $X$ be a random variable which takes values $0,1,2,3,4,5$, and $6$ with the distribution function $f$. The distribution of $X$ is given below
[image: Distribution of X]

What is the simplest way to compute mean, variance, etc from distribution presented like this? From the documentation, `Variance[]` only takes a predefined distribution or a plain list as input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
f = {17, 29, 27, 16, 7, 3, 1}/100;

Variance[EmpiricalDistribution[f -> x]]
```

> 9/5